# Unable to remove task from marathon

Tags: mesos, marathon

Due to my mesos-master suddenly lost connection. It puts marathon in a really odd state where I can not remove tasks.
Wait for marathon to figure out that a task has been lost but I have no way to manually clean it away.

Anyway I can kill the task from Mararthon UI?

> Cannot kill task **** of framework 20150121-162624-453060618-5050-2463-0000 because it cannot be found; cannot send TASK_LOST since a non-strict registry is in use

Comment: Is the master back up and did the Marathon reconnect? Did the slave on which the task is running reconnect as well?

Comment: The master is not back up. I have try to reconnect. Yes, all reconnect. Manage to let it rollback and deploy. But there is no other way it can be remove right?

Comment: Both, Marathon and the slave have to be connected to the master. You should be able to kill a specific task, but it will be redeployed automatically.